# Irreducible polynomial in integer polynomial ring with complex root is a reciprocal polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

I am working on this problem:

Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Show that $p(x)$ is a reciprocal polynomial (i.e., that its coefficients equidistant from either end are equal) if one of its roots is a complex number $z$ with $|z|= 1$.

My thinking so far is:

Let $z  = a+bi$. Then $z = a-bi$ is also a root of $p(x)$, so both $(x-(a+bi))$ and $(x-(a-bi))$ are factors of $p(x)$ $\Rightarrow$ $(x-(a+bi))(x-(a-bi)) = x^2 - 2ax + a^2 + b^2 = x^2-2ax + 1$ is a factor of $p(x)$ (using that $|z| = 1$, and thus, $a^2 + b^2 = 1$).

I suppose that, at this stage, I'm not sure how to use the fact that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to obtain the result. It seems to me that $p(x)$ cannot have any other nontrivial polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ as factors, since $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. But then, how can I know about other factors of $p(x)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  use the fact that the minimal polynomial for the given root is unique.

Comment: $\bar z= \frac{1}{z}$ so $\frac{1}{z}$ is a root, substitute and eliminate fractions and now unicity of the minimal polynomial...

Comment: @lulu I get down to $0 = a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + a_2z^{n-2} + ... + a_n$. How do I conclude the result? Doesn't the minimal polynomial have to be monic?

Comment: If $x_0$ is the special root, then  $x_0^d\times \overline {p\left(\frac 1 {\overline x_0}\right)}=0$ as well so $x_0$ is a root of $q(x)=x^d\times \overline {p\left(\frac 1 {\overline x}\right)}$. By the uniqueness of the minimal polynomial we deduce that $p(x)=\lambda q(x)$ for some constant $\lambda$.  Now argue that $\lambda$ must be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof is due to a classmate of mine:

Let $K$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $\Bbb Z$ and $\sigma\in Aut(K/\Bbb Z)$ such that for every root $\alpha$ of $p(x), \sigma(\alpha)=\dfrac1{\alpha}$. But $\sigma$ sends any root of $p$ to some root of $p$, which means that the set of all roots of $p$ is the same as the set of reciprocals of all roots of $p$. Hence for every root of $p$, its reciprocal is also a root of $p$, and thus $p(x)$ is reciprocal.